# Spark Kafka Streaming making progress but there is no data to be consumed

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a simple Spark Structured streaming job that uses Kafka 0.10 API to read data from Kafka and write to our S3 storage. From the logs I could see that for the each batch that is triggered the streaming application is making progress and is consuming data from source because that **endOffset** is greater than **startOffset** and both are always increasing for each batch. But the **numInputRows** is always zero and there are no rows written to the S3.

Why is there an progressive increase in offsets but no data is consumed by the spark batch?

```
19/09/10 15:55:01 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Streaming query made progress: {
  "id" : "90f21e5f-270d-428d-b068-1f1aa0861fb1",
  "runId" : "f09f8eb4-8f33-42c2-bdf4-dffeaebf630e",
  "name" : null,
  "timestamp" : "2019-09-10T15:55:00.000Z",
  "batchId" : 189,
  "numInputRows" : 0,
  "inputRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
  "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
  "durationMs" : {
    "addBatch" : 127,
    "getBatch" : 0,
    "getEndOffset" : 0,
    "queryPlanning" : 24,
    "setOffsetRange" : 36,
    "triggerExecution" : 1859,
    "walCommit" : 1032
  },
  "stateOperators" : [ ],
  "sources" : [ {
    "description" : "KafkaV2[Subscribe[my_kafka_topic]]",
    "startOffset" : {
      "my_kafka_topic" : {
        "23" : 1206926686,
        "8" : 1158514946,
        "17" : 1258387219,
        "11" : 1263091642,
        "2" : 1226741128,
        "20" : 1229560889,
        "5" : 1170304913,
        "14" : 1207333901,
        "4" : 1274242728,
        "13" : 1336386658,
        "22" : 1260210993,
        "7" : 1288639296,
        "16" : 1247462229,
        "10" : 1093157103,
        "1" : 1219904858,
        "19" : 1116269615,
        "9" : 1238935018,
        "18" : 1069224544,
        "12" : 1256018541,
        "3" : 1251150202,
        "21" : 1256774117,
        "15" : 1170591375,
        "6" : 1185108169,
        "24" : 1202342095,
        "0" : 1165356330
      }
    },
    "endOffset" : {
      "my_kafka_topic" : {
        "23" : 1206928043,
        "8" : 1158516721,
        "17" : 1258389219,
        "11" : 1263093490,
        "2" : 1226743225,
        "20" : 1229562962,
        "5" : 1170307882,
        "14" : 1207335736,
        "4" : 1274245585,
        "13" : 1336388570,
        "22" : 1260213582,
        "7" : 1288641384,
        "16" : 1247464311,
        "10" : 1093159186,
        "1" : 1219906407,
        "19" : 1116271435,
        "9" : 1238936994,
        "18" : 1069226913,
        "12" : 1256020926,
        "3" : 1251152579,
        "21" : 1256776910,
        "15" : 1170593216,
        "6" : 1185110032,
        "24" : 1202344538,
        "0" : 1165358262
      }
    },
    "numInputRows" : 0,
    "inputRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
    "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.0
  } ],
  "sink" : {
    "description" : "FileSink[s3://my-s3-bucket/data/kafka/my_kafka_topic]"
  }
}
```

A simplified version of the spark code is as shown below

```
  val df =  sparkSession
      .readStream
      .format"kafka")
      .options(Map(
      "kafka.bootstrap.servers" -> "host:1009",
      "subscribe" -> "my_kafka-topic",
      "kafka.client.id" -> "my-client-id",
      "maxOffsetsPerTrigger" -> 1000,
      "fetch.message.max.bytes" -> 6048576
    ))
      .load()


  df
    .writeStream
    .partitionBy("date", "hour")
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
    .format("parquet")
    .options(Map("checkpointLocation" -> "checkpoint", "path" -> "data"))
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(Duration("5m")))
    .start()
    .awaitTermination()
```

Edit: from the logs I also see these before each batch is executed

```
19/09/11 02:49:42 INFO Fetcher: [Consumer clientId=my_client_id, groupId=spark-kafka-source-5496988b-3f5c-4342-9361-917e4f3ece51-1340785812-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition my-topic-5 to offset 1168959116.
19/09/11 02:49:42 INFO Fetcher: [Consumer clientId=my_client_id, groupId=spark-kafka-source-5496988b-3f5c-4342-9361-917e4f3ece51-1340785812-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition my-topic-1 to offset 1218619371.
19/09/11 02:49:42 INFO Fetcher: [Consumer clientId=my_client_id, groupId=spark-kafka-source-5496988b-3f5c-4342-9361-917e4f3ece51-1340785812-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition my-topic-8 to offset 1157205346.
19/09/11 02:49:42 INFO Fetcher: [Consumer clientId=my_client_id, groupId=spark-kafka-source-5496988b-3f5c-4342-9361-917e4f3ece51-1340785812-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition my-topic-21 to offset 1255403059.
```

Comment: what is your `checkpoint` settings ? could you put a sample code for `readStream` ?

Comment: @SanBan I just updated the question with a simplified version of the spark code ..

Comment: I had such a problem when I set the number of cores to one. But my code was in Java and I'm not sure if it is true about pyspark to. Increasing the number of the cores resolved that problem because one core is dedicated for managing input data from Kafka.

Comment: @epcpu in your case did the offsets increase progressively for each micro-batch and spark processed no data?

Comment: as a matter of fact, I didn't check the offset, and this was the main source of the doubt I mentioned in the previous comment. But You can try it to find if it is helpful or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check is any of the case related to output directory and checkpoint location mentioned in below link is applicable in your case?

https://kb.databricks.com/streaming/file-sink-streaming.html

Answer (score 2):

This exact issue with updating offsets but no input rows happened to me when I cleaned my checkpoint location to start the streaming afresh but used the old target location (not cleared) for writing the streamed data.  After cleaning (changing) both checkpoint and write location it worked just fine.

In this particular case as I cleared the checkpoint location the offsets were getting updated properly. But because I didn't clear the target location (as it had data from 5-6 months of continuous streaming i.e. 100s of 1000s of small files to delete) but apparently spark checks for the spark metadata and as it found old data in there it didn't consume any new data.